# How to create Custom Tab-Bars in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I want to create a navigation bar that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkvRI.png). I tried using TabNavigation but it does not look like this. I do not know how do it custom.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom header component or use a pre-existing UI library for this purpose. [NativeBase's Segment component](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#segment-inside-header-headref) may accomplish what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to do it using a custom component, it will depend on how you're rendering the header. If you're using `react-navigation`'s header, you can do it like this in your screen:

```
navigationOptions = {
  header: (
    <MyCustomHeader />
  )
};
```

Comment: oh yeah. This is what look for. Thank you !